# Difference in initialazing objects in java

Tags: java, object, inheritance, abstract-class

Let's say I have an abstract class A and a class called B extending it. What's the difference between initializing like this:

```
A objectname=new B();
```

and this

```
B objectname=new B();
```

Comment: This works the same if A is an interface that B implements. If the interface describes the class well enough, then one can change to different implementations without changing the code (except for the one line). For example, the List interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you'd be creating an instance of `B`. The only difference is where you assign this instance. In the first snippet, `objectname` is of type `A`, so you won't be able to use `B`'s methods that aren't in `A` unless you explicitly cast it to `B`.